# ODEINT error - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence (Python model of solar system)

Tags: python

I am creating an orbital model of the solar system so I need to integrate Newton's second law for each planet as a sum. I am using ODEINT and am getting this ValueError but don't know where the actual problem is occurring.
This is my first post so there is a problem with the indentation under the function...

```
def func(Q,t):
G = const.G.value #[m3/(kg s2)]
masses = np.array([1.9891*10**6, 0.33011, 4.8675, 5.9724, 0.64171])*10**24 #[kg]

(x_sun, y_sun, vx_sun, vy_sun,
x_merc, y_merc, vx_merc, vy_merc, 
x_ven, y_ven, vx_ven, vy_ven,
x_earth, y_earth, vx_earth, vy_earth,
x_mars, y_mars, vx_mars, vy_mars) = Q
x = np.array(Q[0::4])
y = np.array(Q[1::4])
vx = np.array(Q[2::4])
vy = np.array(Q[3::4])
accx = np.zeros(len(masses))
accy = np.zeros(len(masses))
for p in range(len(masses)):
    for m in masses:
        i = list(masses).index(m)
        r = np.sqrt((x[2]-x[i])**2 + (y[2]-y[i])**2)
        if r == 0:
            accx[p] = 0
            accy[p] = 0
        else:
            accx[p] += -G*m * (x[p]-x[i])/r**3
            accy[p] += -G*m * (y[p]-y[i])/r**3

dQdt = np.zeros(len(Q))
dQdt[0::4] = vx
dQdt[1::4] = vy     
dQdt[2::4] = accx
dQdt[3::4] = accy

return dQdt 

'''set initial conditions'''
names = np.array(['Sun','Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars'])
G = const.G.value                                                    #[m3/(kg s2)]
semimajor = np.array([0, 57.909, 108.209, 149.596, 227.923])*10**9      
#[m]
masses = np.array([1.9891*10**6, 0.33011, 4.8675, 5.9724, 0.64171])*10**24  #[kg]
x0 = np.array([0, 46.002, 107.476, 147.092, 206.617])*10**9             #[m]
y0 = 0                                     
vx0=0
vy0 = 1000*(G*const.M_sun.value*(1/1e6)*((2/x0)-(1/semimajor)))**0.5 #[m/s]
IV = [x0, y0, vx0, vy0] 

'''set time parameters'''
t_i = 0
year = 31557600 
t_f = 8*year
N = 100
t = np.linspace(t_i, t_f, N)

'''find solution with built-in integrator'''

soln = spi.odeint(func, IV, t)
...


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-209-681766e01086> in <module>
 62 
 63 '''find solution with built-in integrator'''
---> 64 soln = spi.odeint(func, IV, t)
 65 solnT = np.transpose(soln)
 66 x = solnT[0::4]/AU

 ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py 
 in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, r

tol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    231                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    232                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,
--> 233                              int(bool(tfirst)))
    234     if output[-1] < 0:
    235         warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Would you be able to give us the code that you are calling the function with, as well as the full error output (including line number)?

Comment: Including the values of `IV` and `t`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
IV = [x0, y0, vx0, vy0]
```

The `odeint` call determines your output dimensions to be the the dimensions of the initial value by the dimensions of time. Here you have set your initial value to have size four, even though `x0, y0, vx0, vy0` are themselves arrays, your `IV` does not concatenate the arrays, it simply put them in a list of length 4.
Also note that your `IV` needs to be of the same form as your function expects, i.e. in the order and shape of

```
(x_sun, y_sun, vx_sun, vy_sun,
x_merc, y_merc, vx_merc, vy_merc, 
x_ven, y_ven, vx_ven, vy_ven,
x_earth, y_earth, vx_earth, vy_earth,
x_mars, y_mars, vx_mars, vy_mars)
```

Change your IV and variables to have the right shape and concatenate them instead of putting them in a list and your problem will go away.

```
x0 = np.array([0, 46.002, 107.476, 147.092, 206.617])*10**9             #[m]
y0 = np.full(x0.shape, 0.)                               
vx0= np.full(x0.shape, 0.)      
vy0 = 1000*(G*const.M_sun.value*(1/1e6)*((2/x0)-(1/semimajor)))**0.5 #[m/s]

IV = np.vstack([x0, y0, vx0, vy0]).reshape(-1)
```